# Admin power on password appeared?

Tags: bios

I had to do a do a complete restore to my computer (I forgot why.)

Now my `HP laptop notebook 2000` is now asking for me to admin power on password I don't recall setting up a password like that nor would I know how.

I do not want to have to key in two passwords one when it boots up and another one when windows appears. I guessed at the first password and it worked. I just used the password same as my windows.

I just want to know how come it just appeared all of a sudden and what can I do to disable it. I am not a computer whiz so if you do tell me how to disable it please be kind and explain step by step.

Comment: Here's a page from HP that explains how to get into the BIOS settings that @Mat000111 mentions.  http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01443329

Comment: @SteveRindsberg What page???

Comment: {facepalm}  Fixed in the edit.  Thanks for the quick catch, @Moab

Comment: Am I reading the question wrong, or does the OP have the password, just wants to turn it off... should be a simple process or am I missing something?

Comment: @acejavelin You are reading correct, OP has the password which he says is the same as Windows password. Steve Rindsberg's liked doc should be enough I think

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like Then is that not as simple as entering BIOS, go the Security section, and disable/reset all security? The link the first commenter posted gets a person very close.

Comment: She will need step by step instructions, which will be very hard here.

Comment: @acejavelin Yes that is all about it but OP requested step by step solution, which the link doesn't provide and I cannot find either. Hope she gets through

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways of bypassing this. One would involve opening the PC and resetting the CMOS, another would be using a script such as given [here](http://dogber1.blogspot.com/2009/05/table-of-reverse-engineered-bios.html).

In this case I think the best thing to do would be to use the HP provided password reset generator I found after some searching. **[Here](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/System-Halt-Error-Message-or-BIOS-Password-Reset-Generator/m-p/5010033)** is the thread and **[here](https://bios-pw.org/)** is the tool. You should have a **key** being shown (perhaps after entering the wrong password 3 times it seems?) which you would input into that tool. HP's instructions after that are:

1. Use the **unlock code** you generated to enter the BIOS (put the unlock code into your computer where it is asking for the Power on Password).
2. Disable all passwords that are enabled in the BIOS's security menu.
3. If asked for current password - type the **unlock code**
4. For new password, just press **ENTER** key
5. Repeat the same for **verify password** column.

Hope this helps. If it doesn't work I recommend contact HP support directly, either by making a thread in their support forum or by other means.

It will really help if you have another computer or tablet which you can use to access and read these instructions whilst your computer is inaccessible (which I assume you do).

Answer (score 1):

The boot password is set in the BIOS.  I'm not sure how it got turned on but it doesn't look like you are the first.  Since you are not a "computer wiz" you might want to just call HP if your laptop is still under support.

If not you can try to clear the power on password in the bios.

Turn the system on and hit F10 key until you get into the BIOS. 
Use the arrow keys to move to the security tab. 
You should see a power on password.  Move over the power on password and hit enter.  If prompted for the old password use the one you used to power it up.  When prompted to set a new one leave the box blank and hit enter.  You will be asked to confirm the password which you should leave blank.

After you are done go to exit and save changes.

Comment: Thank you so much I know how to do that. You are so kind. Like I said I can get into the computer so if I could not get rid of it all wasn't lost. But it is a pain to have to put a password in when he boots up and then another one to get into windows. Thanks so much God Bless you for helping me. I was reading where someone was telling another person you have to take the bios battery off and reset it. Oh my goodness.